# Picking value from Select command

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data validation list in cell C1. I want to pick the value from cell C1 and apply a filter using it.

The value "Tompo" was hardcoded when I recorded the macro. How do I pick the value from cell C1?

```vb
Sub BUfilter()

    BUfilter Macro
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Combined").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= _
        "Tompo"
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Filtering Field17 using value in cell C1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub BUfilter() 
    ' ' BUfilter Macro 
    dim filter1 as string
    filter1 = Range("C1").value
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Combined").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:= filter1 
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated the code a  little bit - there was a line break character, but no line break and the Select line should be on its own row and not part of the AutoFilter line.  Hope you don't mind - was probably just a formatting error when posted.